# mod_rewrite not working - keep getting 500 Internal Server Error

Tags: php, apache, mod-rewrite

Environment:
Apache 2.0.63
PHP 5.3.x.

My website is www.***********.com/LandlordApp/index.php

I want to be able to redirect all traffic to index file?

I have tried the following, but constantly getting "500 Internal Server Error":

```
<Directory /LandlordApp>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /LandlordApp/
RewriteRule ^index.php$ 
</Directory>
```

All help is very welcome.

Thank you

Comment: did you check the error log?

Comment: Please check the apache error log and add a rewrite error log `RewriteLog /var/mysite/log/rewrite.log RewriteLogLevel 9` into your other rewrite rules - restart apache, try again and examine

Comment: Your `RewriteRule` is missing its right side. The syntax is `RewriteRule pattern newlocation [flags]`

Comment: You mean to use something like `RewriteRule .* index.php [L]`

Answer (score 0):

I would put this in your LandlodApp directory

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.html [L]
</IfModule>
```